# Use AppRTCDemo with custom server

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo

All is in the title, I want to use my custom server inside the AppRTCDemo sample app (https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios/tree/master/ios-example).

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: Custom server for what? The turn? The signalling? Streaming the media?

Comment: I want to use Licode Basic Example in the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run the apprtc app on your server.

you need to get an older version of the apprtc js sample, not sure how far back you need to go, probably a version that fits the dates of when the ios-example you are using started. maybe 
try [this](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/?r=5300)

then apply [this changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756690/apprtcdemo-on-local-server-works-between-browsers-and-android-but-not-on-ios) to the code from the link you provided.

good luck

Comment: Does my server have to be the same as apprtc.appspot.com ?

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean by "the same as apprtc.appspot.com"?

Comment: no, you can run the apprtc app with GAE SDK from your server

Comment: @user1269586, i don't know if you are trying what i suggested but i took a look at the ios-example you are referring to and it seems it is updated to connect to the current apprtc app so disregard what i said about getting an older version of the apprtc app. you can find it here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/webrtc