# Building an App Using WebRTC AppRtc Demo

Tags: android, p2p, webrtc

I have android WebRTC Android demo app code running with `https://apprtc.appspot.com/` server.
But what i want to archive is, I want to replace the server `https://apprtc.appspot.com/` with my own server, i want to also modify/remove the part of the code where it communicants with the server as my server communicates differently.

I want to keep the WebRTC related API calls as it is, and only replace the part of the source code which is communicating with the `https://apprtc.appspot.com/` server.

So basically i want to know, what are the WebRTC APIs that i must call for allowing AV calls using my server, I have STUN/TURN and registration servers.

I just want to reuse the core WebRTC functionality only and write app on top of it.

Can someone please guide me on this!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think something similar to what you want , was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949237/webrtc-apprtcdemo-with-local-server-does-not-work-with-android-native-to-pc-br and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085261/apprtcdemo-with-local-server-works-between-browsers-but-not-android-native-to-br

Comment: i have gone through these questions but they focus on local server which is having slimier functionality as the original server. But my server is completely different than the current server. So i just want the WebRtc media related functionality and rest of the part I will writ new.

Comment: I am also working on something similar. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

you can achive android webrtc app by two ways.. both are working perfectly..
1.
Follow this [example](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/), i have tried it and work success fully.

Only need to make one change is the link provided in this example for gclient config command is older one. Follow your link gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Also make sure that you have oracle jdk-6, other version creates issues while following the steps to get the native code.

2 .
You can use Frozen mountain library, which provides you variety of apis for developing webrtc app..

Hope this will help you.. 
check [here](https://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink)

Comment: webpage not found @Ichigo Kurosaki

Answer (score 0):

I have also created 1 demo project where I set my turn and stun server. There is a site http://sipml5.org which provide good detailing example.

You can download their code and set your own configuration or you can take reference in your application. Created demo project link is http://telzy.webuildapps.co, reference taken from http://sipml5.org/call.htm .

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Looks like you have not provided links in the post, I am not just looking for replacing the TURN/STUN servers but i want to replace complete functionality of the server.

Comment: I have added link there, but no problem you can go from here http://sipml5.org/call.htm?svn=224. There is expert mode is available from where you can change settings. This is only a demo page, whole code you can get from git-hub.

Comment: i am looking for android example, not web based. and also i am looking for WebRtc APIs that i need to call from android app layer.

Comment: If you want to create a separate app then I can be wrong but WEB RTC is real time communication through browser-to-browser. So u can run same web based application into browser. Because given demo app work in both machine and mobile browser.