# Building an Apprtc for native android with nodejs server

Tags: android, node.js, webrtc

I've successfully build the AppRTC for native android by taking code from https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo
 and I'm able to make videocalls providing the address of the demo app ( https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=XXXXXXXX ). Now I have install the nodejs 
and also run the node static server in my system. I also know that to run the app on my local server we have remove Google TURN server. But how to bypass this turn server. I have also read this [ApprtcDemo with local server works between browsers but not Android native to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085261/apprtcdemo-with-local-server-works-between-browsers-but-not-android-native-to-br) but can't able to understand clearly.

The problem is that what I need to make change in my code and how to install turn server for node server so that android can connect to my local server. How to manage the setup of turn server in `Centos7` and what is apprtc.py

I am new to this and does not have much knowledge of server so if i have asked anything wrong so ignore it  but please reply me.

After lots of effort i have install the turn server by following the link https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html

Now i have to change the url in my code but i can't able figure what and where to make change in Apprtc demo sample for native android

Answer (score 0):

nodejs has nothing to do with TURN server, I believe you are using nodejs for signalling. If you do not want to use TURN server then you have to remove this url from iceServer configuration. For TURN server local setup, what TURN server you are trying to setup locally? May be you should find some free TURN serve binary along with setup documentation. But why don't you just try any TURN service available for free or as an evaluation?

[Edited] The purpose of TURN server is to facilitate connectivity when both end point are not able to connect using the local candidates where STUN server helps to identify the server-reflexive candidate and TURN is to allocate a Relay candidate. Just to understand your case, you want to run TURN/STUN server in your LAN setup? then there is no use of TURN I guess as TURN server itself is residing inside of the NAT. The general setup requirement of TURN server is have a public IP address which will be used as a Relay candidate for the end points. If you understand this case and still want to setup TURN inside of NAT then its not a harm but to remind you that you won't be able to use TURN when any end point is our of that LAN.

Comment: Ok then I need to use https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/ server then how do i install in my centos6.5 so that my apprtc demo project get run on local server

Comment: Now I have install the turn server so what changes i have to do in my apprtc java code so that it can run because i have to replace the url https://apprtc.appspot.com

Comment: Ok there is no use of Turn server for lan now i have a node server then what to do in https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo code to run my application on this node server instead of ( https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=XXXXXXXX )

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching on google i have find out my solution from https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc link here you have to use google app engine along node js for making local server.